# Optimize DOM selection in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Here is a commplete [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4QQgU/)

I am new to JavaScript/jQuery plugin.

How to create a jQuery plugin for the following script and DOM selection can be more optimize.

```
var option = {"N":"None","F":"Friends","FF":"Friends of Friends","E":"Everybody"}

$("#uiSettingsPanel").find(".head").click(function(){
    $("#uiSettingsPanel").find(".csli").slideUp();
    $(this).parent().find('.csli').slideDown("slow");   
});

$("#uiSettingsPanel .sli .privacy .row .caption").click(function(){
    $("#uiSettingsPanel .sli .privacy .row .caption")
              .parent().find(".body").slideUp("slow");

    $(this).parent().find(".body").toggle("slow");  
});

$("#uiSettingsPanel .sli .privacy .row .body select").change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".caption .right div")
         .html("<span class='wait'>Please wait...</span>");
        var val = $(this).val();

        var it = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            it.parent().parent().parent()
                 .find(".caption .right div").html(option[val]);
        },4000);    
    });
```

Comment: Go through this: http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery-standards/ . Many tricks for optimizing your code.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you can cache selectors and then use find() to reduce selection range.

Like so:

```
var uiSettingsPanel = $("#uiSettingsPanel");
var row = uiSettingsPanel.find('.sli .privacy .row');

var caption = row.find('.body .caption');
```

You should think of a some cleaver way to reduce the number and the range of DOM selections.

Also avoid DOM selections in event handlers each time (get the elements once, then cache them).

Looking at your code I think you'll be able to reduce .parent() calls.